# Will nest server send the ‘Away’ or ‘Back’ mode to our server?

Tags: firebase, nest-api

The Scenario we want to create is when users set away mode on nest device, our WiFi socket will automatically turn off to save energy. How do we get notified about this scenario? Will nest server send the ‘Away’ or ‘Back’ mode to our server? 
If  yes, what is the detailed procedure? We have looked up nest developers’ website and understood the way to synchronize the data to the client by using firebase. But we haven’t found the way to synchronize the data to our server?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. There are too many aspects in your question, without answering all of them there is no complete solution. But answering all of them is not possible here. Please read [ask]. Note that you must first try something yourself before asking support

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the "away" bucket which has the values "Home" and "away"

There are no callbacks so you will have to monitor for those changes in state.

Firebase gives realtime values of everything in the data model
REST Streaming will also give you realtime values of everything in the data model
Polling will just get you info as whatever frequency you use for polling. You could get the whole data model OR just the single value you are monitoring.

Comment: Our question is how to synchronize the realtime data of nest to our cloud server and so we can control our device according the state of nest ( Value of Home and Away )? 
From the developers' website, we understand that it needs a temporary token to get the realtime data from nest.  This way works for the APP client to get the data from nest. But it doesn't work for the cloud server to get the data from nest.

Comment: For realtime you can use REST Streaming or Firebase. Both offer realtime, but you still will need to go through OAuth first to get your token. The tokens are "temporary" but last like 10 years or until they are manually revoked.

Comment: We have made significant progress with the integration. We are trying to build a feature where if the Nest is set to away, out Wi-Fi sockets will turn off. In order to do this we would have to maintain open connections with each Nest for our users, and currently its not possible. My question is does Nest have another API that would be able to solve this issue for us with our app checking for Nest Away status updates on the front end instead of the backend?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by front end or back end. You could poll for changes every few minutes if keeping a Firebase or REST Streaming connection isn't possible. I think your use case is totally feasible and bad ass, but your three options for status are polling, firebase, or a REST Stream

Comment: @Liav did you end up polling for every user or did you figure out a way to maintain open connections for each user?